# Azure Load Balanced Application error on one server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a application that is load balanced in azure but I have one server that is not working correctly. How can I hit that specific server with my browser to tell what is going on ? Any tricks people know of ?

Comment: What Azure services are you using?

Comment: How can I tell and I will let you know

Comment: Its just external load balancing

Comment: Is this a live production environment? if it's not you could always take other servers/instances offline temporarily to make sure traffic is going to the faulty server only and then debug it..

Comment: Live production servers